# How can my hand connect the rotation of my hand to the special bone IK

Tags: bones

how can i do like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nkNN4aJjjYg), my bone doesnt move [image]

help me with my file https://drive.google.com/file/d/16Zd5wGN8KDUNh0f15d8-blnxXYnOaxdO/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have enabled *Tool Settings > Pose Options > Affect Only > `[X]` Locations*. When this is enabled you cannot change the rotation and scale of any bone.

Deactivate it either in the *Pose Options* dropdown menu, or in the N-panel, or in the *Properties Editor* on the right side.

[image: pose options - affect only locations]

The *SpecialBoneIK* has an IK bone constraint on it. Remove it because that's not correct. Also maybe rename the bone to *LeftHandIK*?

In *Edit* mode, you need to change the parent of this bone to the root bone *Original*. And make it the parent of the 5 finger bones (keep offset).

Then in *Pose* mode, you can add the bone constraint to the left forearm as shown in the video. Or select them both (the forearm must be selected last) then use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to add the constraint.

Last but not least, add the *pole target* for the hand. Make it a child of the *Original* bone.

Don't forget to disable *Bone Properties > `[_]` Deform* for the *LeftHandIK*/*SpecialBoneIK* and the *pole target* bone. It's not shown in the video but you don't want them to deform your mesh later.